# AppCenter build error: Project firebaseauth_web at : is either no Android app project or build version has not been set to override

Tags: firebase, flutter, gradle, visual-studio-app-center

I have a mobile project in flutter and I am trying to build it on `AppCenter` but I got this error:

```
Project firebaseauth_web at : is either no Android app project or build version has not been set to override. Skipping...


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/runner/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_web-0.1.3+1/android/build.gradle' line: 22

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'firebaseauth_web'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.library']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.4.1. Current version is 4.10.2. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/runner/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_web-0.1.3+1/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-5.4.1-all.zip

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

The plugin firebase_auth_web could not be built due to the issue above.

##[error]The process '/bin/bash' failed with exit code 1
##[error]Bash failed with error: The process '/bin/bash' failed with exit code 1
##[section]Finishing: Post Clone Script
##[section]Starting: Checkout Chofu@master to s
==============================================================================
Task         : Get sources
Description  : Get sources from a repository. Supports Git, TfsVC, and SVN repositories.
Version      : 1.0.0
Author       : Microsoft
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798199)
==============================================================================
Cleaning any cached credential from repository: Chofu (ExternalGit)
##[section]Finishing: Checkout Chofu@master to s
##[section]Starting: Finalize Job
Cleaning up task ***
Start cleaning up orphan processes.
Terminate orphan process: pid (1490) (java)
Terminate orphan process: pid (1470) (java)
Terminate orphan process: pid (1462) (java)
Terminate orphan process: pid (1404) (java)
Terminate orphan process: pid (1289) (adb)
##[section]Finishing: Finalize Job
##[section]Finishing: Build
```

My `gradle` version is actually `6.1.1`.

Here is my `gradle-wrapper.properties` from `android/gradle` code:

```
...
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
...
```

I have tried to change the version to `5.4.1` but I got a similar error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


* Where:

Build file '/Users/runner/runners/2.170.1/work/1/s/android/app/build.gradle' line: 24



* What went wrong:

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.version-check']

   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.1.1. Current version is 5.4.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/runner/runners/2.170.1/work/1/s/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-6.1.1-all.zip



* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org




BUILD FAILED in 18s

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           19.8s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

**EDITED:**

After a better look I discover other 2 errors:

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.


1: Task failed with an exception.

-----------

* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':appcenter:verifyReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

   > 1 exception was raised by workers:

     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed

     /Users/runner/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/469951e99791312bb8bf182873580e29/core-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.



     /Users/runner/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/469951e99791312bb8bf182873580e29/core-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.







* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

==============================================================================



2: Task failed with an exception.

-----------

* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':appcenter_analytics:verifyReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

   > 1 exception was raised by workers:

     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed

     /Users/runner/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/469951e99791312bb8bf182873580e29/core-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.



     /Users/runner/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/469951e99791312bb8bf182873580e29/core-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
```

If someone could help me I would be grateful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After one month of struggle I found how to solve the problem:

1. I have changed **gradle version** from **android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties** from **6.1.1** to **5.6.2** . So my file looks like:

```
...
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
...
```

2. In **android/build.gradle** I have changed **gradle tool version** from **4.0.0** to **3.5.0**:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        ...
    }
```

3. In **android/app/build.gradle** I have added `checkReleaseBuilds false` to `lintOptions` :

```
lintOptions {
        ...
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
```

4. In **android/app/appcenter-post-clone.sh** I have added two builds before `--release` build:

```
...
# build APK
flutter build apk --debug
flutter build apk --profile
flutter build apk --release
...
```

I hope this will help others :)